# Import php variable into the .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/site/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/inicio?$ site/$1/index.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ site/$1/pagina.php?pagina=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/noticia/([^/]+)/?$ site/$1/pagina.php?pagina=noticia&id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/cadastro-ativar/([^/]+)/?$ site/$1/pagina.php?pagina=cadastro-ativar&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

I would go with a php variable, or otherwise. The intention is more to incurtar URL.

Thus theoretically, at line 4.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^$modeloSite/site/ [NC]         <<<<<<<<<
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you want that? What's the purpose? Give an example. (Apache interprets the RewriteRules before PHP comes into play; and there's no interaction. Only a `RewriteMap` workaround might be able to hook into a script.)

Comment: Why would you need a PHP variable in .htaccess? Can you clarify?

Comment: you can't put php (variables OR code) into any of apache's runtime directives. you could CAPTURE the $modelSite value in the request uri  and use that, e.g. `RewriteCond ... ^(.*?)/site/`

Comment: @anubhava My site has multiple folders. Each folder is a website template. The model that recorded this should open the database. I just need to get this value and bring into the htaccess file.

Comment: I don't think mod_rewrite or htaccess can do all that.

Comment: you could define an environment variable with PHP and then access it in your .htaccess file. No idea if .htaccess has support fot something like "ifdefined"

Comment: additionally you could try to access and use GET/POST variables

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Figure out a solution! 
Instead of importing the variable, every client command when changing layout of the script creates a new htaccess file.

```
$fp = fopen("../.htaccess", "w");
fwrite($fp, "
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/site/$modeloAtivado/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]


RewriteRule ^inicio?$ site/$modeloAtivado/index.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ site/$modeloAtivado/pagina.php?pagina=$1&id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^noticia/([^/]+)/?$ site/$modeloAtivado/pagina.php?pagina=noticia&id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^cadastro-ativar/([^/]+)/?$ site/$modeloAtivado/pagina.php?pagina=cadastro-ativar&id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^fatura/([^/]+)/?$ site/$modeloAtivado/pagina.php?pagina=fatura&ref=$1 [L,QSA]
");
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: PHP won't be invoked until *after* the `.htaccess` file has been consulted. So you'd write a file with each request, which would be checked by the *next* request, which would do what, exactly? I guess what I'm saying is, this seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: @pjmorse Because you became negative me? I tested this and running the code above. Is working exactly as I need.

Answer (score 0):

There is simply no way to use php variables directly in your htaccess file...

Unless.. you opt for the absolutely nasty method of making your .htaccess file writable and overwriting it every time.. but if you decide on that method you don't deserver to be a programmer :)

Your other option though, is a method ie. wordpress chose to use too.. that being: simply redirect all your traffic to your index.php (which is a very often used method) and take care of redirecting there.

You can't really call it rewriting, since you dont have to rewrite your url at that point, but you can decide what files to include, what controllers to load or whatever you use in your application.

Comment: This is probably the only sane approach: send all your traffic to one PHP script and handle the routing there.